# How to trigger component events from any other component in the app using vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a component (countdown timer) that is going to be running on all pages of the site. It's referenced in the top-level App.vue file.  I need to be able to call events inside that component (to restart the time) from ANY other component inside the app regardless of how deep down the hierarchy chain it is (meaning, I don't want to run events and $emits through every single component on the site for this one thing).

Anytime that I make an ajax call to the server, I want to reset the timer.  So every time a button is clicked in the code below, I want to trigger the `startCountdown(true)` event on the countdown timer component.

[Here's a codesandbox example of what I'm doing.](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-76j14?fontsize=14)

**Main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import router from "./router/router";
import VueAwesomeCountdown from "vue-awesome-countdown";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAwesomeCountdown);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  getters: {
    count: state => {
      return state.count;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  },
  actions: {
    increment: context => {
      context.commit("increment");
    },
    decrement: context => {
      context.commit("decrement");
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store,
  template: "<App />",
  components: {
    App
  }
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/" class="btn bt-link">Page 1</router-link>&nbsp;|
    <router-link to="/Page2" class="btn bt-link">Page 2</router-link>&nbsp;|
    <router-link to="/Page3" class="btn bt-link">Page 3</router-link>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <br>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <br>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <!-- Timer countdown -->
    <countdown ref="sessionTimer" :left-time="99000">
      <span slot="process" slot-scope="{ timeObj }">Session Timer Countdown: {{ timeObj.ceil.s }}</span>
      <span slot="finish">TIMED OUT!</span>
    </countdown>
    <button class="ml-3 btn btn-warning" @click="restart">Manual Restart</button>
    <hr>
    <!-- The below is just show vuex is wired up correctly -->
    <p>This is just to show that Vuex is working properly.</p>
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
    <p>
      <button @click="increment">+</button>
      <button @click="decrement">-</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    count() {
      return this.$store.getters.count;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    restart() {
      this.$refs.sessionTimer.startCountdown(true);
    },
    increment() {
      this.$store.dispatch("increment");
    },
    decrement() {
      this.$store.dispatch("decrement");
    }
  },
  components: {}
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

**Page2.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="interactWithServer">Interact with Server 2</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <SubComponent></SubComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SubComponent from "./Page2-SubComponent.vue";

export default {
  methods: {
    interactWithServer() {
      //This function will interact with server but I need to start countdown timer over again first
      //axios call goes here after timer is reset
    }
  },
  components: {
    SubComponent
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
</style>
```

**Page-SubComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>SUB COMPONENT</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="interactWithServer">Interact with Server 2.1</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    interactWithServer() {
      //This function will interact with server but I need to start countdown timer over again first
      //axios call goes here after timer is reset
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if there is a shorter way but you can trigger a variable on the store and then listen to that from the `App.vue` file then execute `restart` open that .. here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-b0rjz) sample

```js
// store

state: {
  changed: false
}

getters: {
  changed: (state) => state.changed
}

mutation: {
  changed: (state) => state.changed = !state.changed
}
```

```js
// App.vue

 computed: {
    trigger() {
      return this.$store.getters.changed
    }
  },
  methods: {
    restart() {
      this.$refs.sessionTimer.startCountdown(true);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    trigger() {
      this.restart()
    }
  }
```

on your other components :

```js
interactWithServer() {
  this.$store.commit("changed");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me!  I was hoping to not have to use a watcher but it's better than nothing! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to save the number of the timer in **:left-time="99000"** in the store and when you trigger the event in **interactWithServer()** reset it?

***Main.js*** (additional code)

```
state:{
  timer: 99000
},
getters: {
  getTimer: state => {
    return state.timer;
  }
},
mutations: {
  resetTimer: state => state.timer = 99000
},
actions: {
  restartTimer: context => {
    context.commit("resetTimer");
  }
}
```

***App.vue*** (modifed code)

```
</template>
    <countdown ref="sessionTimer" :left-time="timer">
      <span slot="process" slot-scope="{ timeObj }">Session Timer Countdown: {{ timeObj.ceil.s }}</span>
      <span slot="finish">TIMED OUT!</span>
    </countdown>
</template>
<script>
  computed: {
    timer() {
      return this.$store.getters.timer;
    }
  },
</script>
```

And in **interactWithServer()** call ***this.$store.dispatch("restartTimer");***

Comment: I don't think it works like that.  Simply updating the left-time value doesn't do anything. You have to use the component's startCountdown(true) method, I believe.